# Proving that the CDF of any CDF is a Constant Number

Tags: probability

If $X$ is a random variable, we define the probability distribution function (PDF) of $X$ as $f(x)$ and the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of $X$ as $F(X)$. As such, the cdf can be written in different ways:

$$F(X = a) = P(X \leq a) = \int_{-\infty}^{a} f(x) \, dx$$

**I am trying to prove the following relationship:** The CDF of ANY CDF has a  Uniform Probability Distribution

I think I was able to prove this indirectly:

- Part 1: In general, the following properties are true about functions:

$$y = f(x)$$
$$f^{-1}(y) = x $$
$$f(f^{-1}(y)) = y$$

- Part 2: If we have some CDF $F(X=x)$, then we can write the "CDF of this CDF" as:

$$F[F(X=x)=y] = P[F(X=x) \leq y] = P[X \leq F^{-1}(y)] = F [F^{-1}(y)] = y$$

Here, $y$ is a **constant number.**

- Part 3: If $X$ has a Uniform(0,1) distribution, the CDF of $X$  is then $x$. Intutively, imagine a rectangle of width = 1 (i.e. 0:1) and height = 1 (i.e.0:1). This means that if you choose some point $x$ on the width, the area from the origin to this point $x$ will be $x$ ... for all $x$. Here, $x$ is a **constant number.**

Thus, I have shown that the CDF  of any CDF is a constant number, and the CDF of a Uniform Distribution is also a constant number. Therefore, the claim is true.

Is my proof correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Yep, thats right, you just have to prove that $F_{Y}(y) = y$ for $0<y<1$
and that's what you did

Comment: @ daniel: thank you so much!

Comment: PDF = probability density function.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to clarify what you are trying to prove.  I don't understand what "CDF of a CDF" means.  Note that the notation for the CDF is $F(x)$, not $F(X=x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but I think there are a few things you should be careful about. In particular, PDF is short for probability density function, not probability distribution function. Also, a CDF is just a function $F: \mathbb R \to [0, 1]$, so (if $F$ is the CDF of a random variable $X$) people usually write $F(a) = P(X \leq a)$, not $F(X = a)$. So part 2 should go something like, for $0 < y < 1$,
$$
  P(F(X) \leq y) = P(X \leq F^{-1}(y)) = F(F^{-1}(y)) = y.
$$
so the CDF of $F(X)$ (which is not $F$!) is exactly the uniform CDF, so $F(X)$ is uniformly distributed.

Comment: As for part 3, yes, assuming you are imagining the integral of a constant density.

Comment: @ daisies: thank you so much for your answer! I accepted it

Comment: I wonder why this question was suddenly downvoted and closed?